# How would I go about embedding JSON data into my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, json, html, base64

I'm currently working on a project where I'm creating a playable ad I'd like to upload to Facebook.

According to Facebook's ad specifications: (https://www.facebook.com/business/help/412951382532338?helpref=faq_content) 
They only accept a single HTML file of size less than 2mb for uploading. This means I need to inline all external references to a single HTML file. Which brings me to my problem:
In order to speed up development I use game engines like PlayCanvas and Phaser Editor. The issue I'm facing with most game engines is that they always have data stored in a JSON file that makes it difficult to reference into an HTML file. Is there any way I can inline this data into my file as well?

JSON data containing a base64 encoded image:

```
"section": [{
    "type": "image",
    "key": "logo",
    "url": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEn.........",
   "overwrite": false
  }],
  "meta": {
    "generated": "1543491968969",
    "app": "Phaser Editor",
    "url": "http://phasereditor.boniatillo.com",
    "version": "1.0",
    "copyright": "Arian Fornaris (c) 2015,2016"
  }
}
```

Function that references this data in my HTML file:

```
Level.prototype.preload = function () 
  {
    this.load.pack('section', 'assets/pack.json');
  };
```

Is there a way I can load the referenced data from the JSON file into this function? I've tried using

```
<script id="data" type="application/json">
    {
        JSON data here
    }
</script>
```

and then inlining code inside the braces. Replacing 'assets/pack.json' with this code. I've also tried replacing 'section' with it's respective JSON data but I've not been successful. I hope there's someone out there who can understand how this function works and how it would be possible to inline this data there.

I'm also curious if there are any game engines or softwares that would output a single HTML file that I could use in my development.

I'd like to thank everyone in advance and I appreciate any help in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by creating a HTML field which is hidden and setting it's data- to be an object like this.

`<div data-foobar='{"foo":"bar"}'></div>`

Check out this link :

http://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/Q6kKU/